# Ensure percentages are between 0 and 1, inclusive (using a single function)

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-12c

I have percentages in a `condition` table:

```
create table condition (percent_decimal number(3,2));
insert into condition values (-0.01);
insert into condition values (0.1);
insert into condition values (1);
insert into condition values (1.1);
commit;

PERCENT_DECIMAL
---------------
          -0.01
             .1
              1
            1.1
```

I want to select the values, but modify them to present them as percentages between 0 and 1 (inclusive):

- Convert `-0.01` to `0`
- Leave `.1` as is
- Leave `1` as is
- Convert `1.1` to `1`

I can successfully do this using the [greatest](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions060.htm) and [least](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions075.htm) functions:

```
select
    percent_decimal,
    least(1,greatest(0,percent_decimal)) as percent_modified
from
    condition

PERCENT_DECIMAL PERCENT_MODIFIED
--------------- ----------------
          -0.01                0
             .1               .1
              1                1
            1.1                1
```

**However, I'm wondering if there is a more succinct way of doing this--with a single function.**

I'm often pleasantly surprised by the clever techniques that DBA-SE members come up with. When I think I've come up with the simplest way to do something, someone comes up with something *even simpler*.

Comment: Oracle does allow you to define your own functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this can't be a serious question, reminds me of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

I can do better, no function at all.

```
select
  percent_decimal,
  case
    when percent_decimal <= 0 then 0
    when percent_decimal >= 1 then 1
    else percent_decimal
  end as percent_modified
from condition;

PERCENT_DECIMAL PERCENT_MODIFIED
--------------- ----------------
          -0.01                0
             .1               .1
              1                1
            1.1                1
```

But we need a function. Finally Oracle 12.2 allows long (128 bytes) identifiers, so we can give more meaningful names:

```
with function 
  "Convert -0.01 to 0, Leave .1 as is, Leave 1 as is, Convert 1.1 to 1" (p number)
return number
as
begin
  if (p = -0.01) then return 0; end if;
  if (p = 1.1) then return 1; end if;
  return p;
end;
select
  percent_decimal,
  "Convert -0.01 to 0, Leave .1 as is, Leave 1 as is, Convert 1.1 to 1"(percent_decimal) 
    as percent_modified
from condition;

PERCENT_DECIMAL PERCENT_MODIFIED
--------------- ----------------
          -0.01                0
             .1               .1
              1                1
            1.1                1
```

I also happen to have a super [secret function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-source-text-wrapping.html#GUID-AB6FFBAD-DE20-4197-A885-AF81F3766FA2) that coincidentally does exactly what you need:

```
create or replace function "." wrapped
a000000
1
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
8
97 aa
30RI5qP/Li6VhppxgO2AXQw62mYwg1xfrZ6pfI6iO8cYr/L9s3tguDonZ52omRm1G6sfUCen
xkcEU/4jCxrp7Ii4VNrCrVY6cDr0UNz1Id5vZ5p7e0S0F+AEd55sz9JyGokPaBbDJHFVdW+A
IAHg6Xpxmglu3BtbDtBmCA==

/
```

> ```
> select
>   percent_decimal,
>   "."(percent_decimal) as percent_modified
> from condition;
>
> PERCENT_DECIMAL PERCENT_MODIFIED
> --------------- ----------------
>           -0.01                0
>              .1               .1
>               1                1
>             1.1                1
> ```

Must use a built-in function? No problem.

```
select
  percent_decimal,
  round(percent_decimal/1.05, 1) as percent_modified
from condition;

PERCENT_DECIMAL PERCENT_MODIFIED
--------------- ----------------
          -0.01                0
             .1               .1
              1                1
            1.1                1
```